# Does Linux have similar apps of Microsoft or Google?

Tags: linux, windows, application, google

I am a Windows user, sometimes using Ubuntu, and I use the default apps given by Microsoft for certain tasks, like Word, Excel and PowerPoint. Later, I realized that Google has the same kind of apps: Docs, Sheets, Slides.

Are there similar apps made by Linux?

Comment: Not by Linux - but look for [Apache Open Office](https://www.openoffice.org/) amongst others (these work on Windows, and osx and linux).

Comment: I am not using Windows, hence I am curious about "the default apps given by Microsoft". Are Word, Excel and PowerPoint currently available for free by default? I cannot find any official statement supporting the statement.

Comment: @Hermann The programs are free and can be preinstalled, but you will need an Office 365 subscription to continue using it. Though there are many free online versions of these apps.

Comment: @MrR, Apache OpenOffice is dead. Look for the fork LibreOffice (comes packaged with most Linux distributions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is a platform based on so called Linux kernel and unix like system layout and utilities and majority of software tools available there comes either from original unix platforms or the community. Where people from community time to time form also commercial projects and release software under somewhat closed source license, majority of linux software that is not part of the unix heritage originates from opensource community and enthusiasts.

Regarding office software... around 1990+ somewhat association so called OpenOffice formed and when you search it on the internet, https://www.openoffice.org/ still exists and you can get the software from there.

During the years there were some cooperation and misunderstandings during the development of the project and there were some stages when the OpenOffice project changed and become LibreOffice software package ... while this overal initiative was dropped somewhere along the road and now both OpenOffice and LibreOffice office software packages (exist for all to use, as both of these packages are distributed to most of the meaningful platforms today.

for sure uncle google if you ask him like "office software best free linux  alternatives" will reveal a lot of similar content.

just three first links ...
https://linuxhint.com/best_ms_office_alternatives_linux/
https://itsfoss.com/best-free-open-source-alternatives-microsoft-office/
https://www.ubuntupit.com/top-10-best-free-office-suite-software-as-ms-office-alternative-for-linux/

while these days number of online services exists for the same.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Not *quite* right. Very few (if any) of the userland in typical Linux installations comes "from original Unix platforms". Much of the base tools are clones of Unix software (e.g. the whole GNU project), most of the basic management tools are original designs, and a truckload of software was written for generic Unix systems (and Linux is --by design-- quite close) and ported to Linux.

Comment: The sad story of OpenOffice is told e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice), short version is that OpenOffice is dead for all purposes, today the development continues with [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org), which is what is shipped with most Linux distributions.